# How to fix `ubi-timezone failed with exit code 2` error in Lubuntu 18.04 install?

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu

It happened in fresh install from DVD of Lubuntu 18.04.

I know about [How to fix `ubi-timezone failed with exit code 1` error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251358/how-to-fix-ubi-timezone-failed-with-exit-code-1-error/) but this is a different exit code.

Comment: What machine are you using?  in particular what cpu & amount of memory. I have never seen the message you mention, but the link you gave includes cases where the alternate installer should have been used (default installer runs in live mode plus installer ubiquity needs ram; problems can occur if too little ram thus alternate installer). Does it stop your install? if not I'd just let it install, and set the timezone post-install (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime though that was written for gnome so screens/dialog will be different)